# sql query to python django query

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm new to Django and SQL. I have this following SQL query. How to implement the same in the Django query?

```
"SELECT DISTINCT C1.CLASSDESC AS CLASS,C2.CLASSCODE AS CODE, C1.CARDCATEGORY AS CATEGORY, C2.CLASSBENEFITS BENEFITS FROM CARDCLASSMAPPING C1,CARDCLASSMASTER C2 WHERE C1.ISACTIVE = 1 AND C2.ISACTIVE = 1 AND C1.CLASSDESC = C2.CLASSDESC AND C1.SCHEMETYPE = ? AND C1.SCHEMECODE = ? AND C1.GLCODE = ? AND C1.ACCOUNTCATEGORY = ? ORDER BY CLASS";
```

Comment: You should specify the Django models and add code.

Comment: WHY ARE YOUR MODELS SHOUTING AT ME? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/) to understand how queries can be constructed in Django. Django provides ORM API to fetch data from your database easily using queries like this:

```
CardClassMapping.objects.get(id=1)
```

In order to use the above line of code, you should have a model named `CardClassMapping` to get the objects from.

Also, you can use raw SQL like this:

```
CardClassMapping.objects.raw('SELECT DISTINCT C1.CLASSDESC AS CLASS,C2.CLASSCODE AS CODE, C1.CARDCATEGORY AS CATEGORY, C2.CLASSBENEFITS BENEFITS FROM CARDCLASSMAPPING C1')
```

For more on raw SQL: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/

Comment: I  want to query as same as in the SQL query in Django, but using Django queries.